# Query multiple tables in different database with the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple databases and their names are in masterDBTable.

MasterDBTable

ID    DBName

1. CustomerDB1
2. CustomerDB2
3. CustomerDB3

In each of these DB's, there's a table called clients

How would I loop through and insert all the clients from each DB into a temp table? 
When I try I get the following error:

"variable assignment is not allowed in a cursor declaration."

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @DataBaseName VARCHAR
    ,@SQL NVARCHAR

CREATE TABLE #TempClient (ClientName VARCHAR(50))

DECLARE clients CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT DISTINCT @DataBaseName = DataBaseName
FROM AIMS.DataBaseMaster

OPEN clients

FETCH NEXT
FROM clients
INTO @DataBaseName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #TempClient(ClientName)
     SELECT ClientName FROM ' + @DataBaseName + '.[Example].[Clients]'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
END

CLOSE clients

DEALLOCATE clients

SELECT *
FROM #TempClient
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the variable here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  @DataBaseName = DataBaseName
          FROM AIMS.DataBaseMaster
```

to

```
SELECT DISTINCT  DataBaseName
          FROM AIMS.DataBaseMaster
```

Also

after

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

add

```
   FETCH NEXT FROM clients INTO @DataBaseName
```

to get the next element in the cursor